# How to get correct number from args?

Tags: c++, c

I write an application, which get a number from args.

ex:./app --addr 0x123 or ./app --addr 123

I don't know which api can identify if the parameter is hex or decimal and come up with the correct data？

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the world of CLI interfaces :)  ``sscanf`` is the usual start point for these kinds of things. For an example, see [this console program](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/tree/main/Texconv) which has a lot of options.

Comment: Please tag only C _or_ C++. The answers to your question are likely to be different between the two languages, at least regarding best-practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of getting the arguments is through `argc` and `argv` in

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Some code here.
    return;
}
```

This will give you an array with all the arguments as strings. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << "Argument " << i << ": " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

will give you this output

```
$ ./app --addr 0x123
Argument 0: ./app
Argument 1: --addr
Argument 2: 0x123
```

Now, parsing the input is a bit more complicated. You could create your own logic to evaluate the arguments once you have the arguments as strings.

You could also use libraries. For example, you could use `argparse` by `p-ranav`. GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/p-ranav/argparse). It is an easy to use library so you don't have to worry about positioning of the arguments.

Answering you question, **how do you know if the input is hex or decimal?** You could check if the argument after `--addr` starts with `0x` or not. That could be one way, but you have to also consider the case when someone inputs a hex value without the `0x`, like `./app --addr A2C`. Also, documenting acceptable formats and printing a `--help` message can ameliorate this.

You have to think about your specific application, but some steps once you have the string after `--addr` that you could do to check input is:

- Does it start with `0x`?
- If not, does it contains characters `0-1` and `A-F`? Is this allowed?
- Is it in a valid range?

  - For example, `0xFFFFF` is 1,048,575. But you may only want addresses up to `0xFFFF` (65,535). What should happen in these cases?

Hope it helps!

P.S.: These are all implementations in C++.

Answer (score 1):

strtol will do the job for you

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/